# Maven dependency conflict with Jersey

Tags: maven, dependencies, jersey

Im developing a rest service with jersey. The project got several modules. My dependencies for my facade module are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<artifactId>com-myproject</artifactId>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject.facade</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-myproject-facade</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>com-myproject-facade Jersey Webapp</name>
   <properties>
    <jersey-version>1.8</jersey-version>
   </properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey-version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.distributions</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-all</artifactId>
  <version>10.0-build-20080430</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
  <artifactId>gf-embedded-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Hyperlinking -->

</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>glassfish.java.net</id>
  <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>m2.java.net</id>
  <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
  <id>m2.java.net</id>
  <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
<finalName>com-bachelor-facade</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It works.

When I add a new dependency for hypermedia with jersey:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server-linking</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey-version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

I get a pom error in this facade project and in all other sibling modules, beacause they depend on the facade module.

In the facade project I get the error about missing artifacts:

```
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact   org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
 22.06.12 11:11:02 MESZ: Missing artifact stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

and so on.

The other modules depend on this project an get the error:

```
 Build errors for com-myproject-core; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project com-myproject-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject.core:com-bachelor-myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.myproject.facade:com-myproject-facade:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8 (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.2 (test), com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8 (test), org.glassfish.distributions:web-all:jar:10.0-build-20080430 (test), org.glassfish.embedded:gf-embedded-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 (test), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 (provided)]
```

I think I just need to maven install the changed project with maven and then the other projects get fixed. But I cant do maven install, because the changed project pom is red too caused by missing artifacts. How to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you install the missing artifacts, too.